# Slice a Pandas dataframe with DatetimeIndex based on time interval

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, slice

I'm trying to accomplish the following...

I got a Pandas dataframe that have a number of entries, indexed with DatetimeIndex which looks a bit like this:

```
bro_df.info()

<class 'bat.log_to_dataframe.LogToDataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 3596641 entries, 2017-12-14 13:52:01.633070 to 2018-01-03 09:59:53.108566
Data columns (total 20 columns):
conn_state        object
duration          timedelta64[ns]
history           object
id.orig_h         object
id.orig_p         int64
id.resp_h         object
id.resp_p         int64
local_orig        bool
local_resp        bool
missed_bytes      int64
orig_bytes        int64
orig_ip_bytes     int64
orig_pkts         int64
proto             object
resp_bytes        int64
resp_ip_bytes     int64
resp_pkts         int64
service           object
tunnel_parents    object
uid               object
dtypes: bool(2), int64(9), object(8), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 528.2+ MB
```

What I'm interested in is getting a slice of this data that takes the last entry, 2018-01-03 09:59:53.108566' in this case, and then subtracts an hour from that. This should give me the last hours worth of entries.

What I've tried to do so far is the following:

```
last_entry = bro_df.index[-1:]
first_entry = last_entry - pd.Timedelta('1 hour')
```

Which gives me what to me looks like fairly correct values, as per:

```
print(first_entry)
print(last_entry)

DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-03 08:59:53.108566'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ts', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-03 09:59:53.108566'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ts', freq=None)
```

This is also sadly where I get stuck. I've tried various things with bro_df.loc and bro_df.iloc and so on but all I get is different errors for datatypes and not in index etc. Which leads me to think that I possibly might need to convert the first_entry, last_entry variables to another type?

Or I might as usual be barking up entirely the wrong tree.

Any assistance or guidance would be most appreciated.

Cheers, Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need create scalars by indexing `[0]` and select by `loc`:

```
df = bro_df.loc[first_entry[0]: last_entry[0]]
```

Or select by [exact indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#exact-indexing):

```
df = bro_df[first_entry[0]: last_entry[0]]
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='2H 24T')
bro_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (bro_df)
                     a
2017-04-03 00:00:00  0
2017-04-03 02:24:00  1
2017-04-03 04:48:00  2
2017-04-03 07:12:00  3
2017-04-03 09:36:00  4
2017-04-03 12:00:00  5
2017-04-03 14:24:00  6
2017-04-03 16:48:00  7
2017-04-03 19:12:00  8
2017-04-03 21:36:00  9
```

---

```
last_entry = bro_df.index[-1:]
first_entry = last_entry - pd.Timedelta('3 hour')
print (last_entry)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-04-03 21:36:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='144T')

print (first_entry)
DatetimeIndex(['2017-04-03 18:36:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

print (last_entry[0])
2017-04-03 21:36:00

print (first_entry[0])
2017-04-03 18:36:00

df = bro_df.loc[first_entry[0]: last_entry[0]]
print (df)
                     a
2017-04-03 19:12:00  8
2017-04-03 21:36:00  9

df1 = bro_df[first_entry[0]: last_entry[0]]
print (df1)
                     a
2017-04-03 19:12:00  8
2017-04-03 21:36:00  9
```

Comment: Works perfectly - once again many thanks for a quick and great solution!

Comment: Amazing solution. Saved me from panicking.